# Form recovery add-on/plugin for IE8?

Tags: internet-explorer, browser-addons, plugins

I'm in search for a "[Lazarus](http://getlazarus.com/) like" add-on/plugin for IE8 which does form recovery (autosaves everything you type into any given web-form).

Any ideas?